# How to execute SQL transaction Async in ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asynchronous

I have webservice with many connections to it.
I used this code:

```
IAsyncResult result = sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
```

I think this is not a best method because I call `Sleep()`.
PS. This method will be slow down performance of WebService and server

**UPDATE2:**
i try to describe my code more:
i have WebClient and 2 event (`ProgressChanged` and `DownloadCompleted`)

```
[WebMethod]
public void DonwloadFromRemoteServer(string uniqueId, string url)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(uniqueId))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uniqueId);

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => wc_DownloadProgressChanged(sender, args, uniqueId, Path.GetFileName(url));

    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) => wc_DownloadFileCompleted(sender, args, uniqueId, Path.GetFileName(url));
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), String.Format("{0}\\{1}", uniqueId, Path.GetFileName(url)));
}

void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, string uniqueId, string fileName)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=XRingtoneDB;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand.Connection = connection;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = String.Format("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT uniqueId FROM downloads WHERE uniqueID = '{0}') " +
                                       "INSERT INTO downloads VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}') " +
                                       "IF EXISTS(SELECT uniqueId FROM downloads WHERE uniqueID = '{0}') " +
                                       "Update downloads " +
                                       "set progress='{2}' " +
                                       "where uniqueId='{0}' ", uniqueId, fileName, e.BytesReceived);

    AsyncCallback callback = ((result) =>
    {
        sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
        connection.Close();
    });

    sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, sqlCommand);
}

void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, string uniqueId, string fileName)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=XRingtoneDB;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand.Connection = connection;

    sqlCommand.CommandText = String.Format("update downloads " +
                                                "set progress='Completed' " +
                                                "where uniqueId='{0}' and fileName='{1}'", uniqueId, fileName);

    AsyncCallback callback = ((result) =>
    {
        sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
        sqlCommand.Connection.Close();
    });
    sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, sqlCommand);
}
```

`ProgressChanged` works fine but `DownloadCompleted` only works in Debug mode.
I think it's happened because I need timeout or wait something between these calls.

**Update3:**
Sometime i have TWO same row in DB after execute download! *confused*
And did I need to close all connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the overload of [BeginExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx) that accepts a callback and in the callback end the query.

**Update**

If you have additional code that needs to be executed after the database execution has completed, then this code needs to be started in the callback.

For example, if you currently have:

```
sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, sqlCommand);
DoSomeAdditionalWorkNow();
```

`DoSomeAdditionalWorkNow` will not wait until the query has completed and if it depends on data updated in the command, you will have problems.

This can be remedied by moving the call to the additional work method into the callback as such:

```
AsyncCallback callback = ((result) =>
{
    sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
    connection.Close();
    DoSomeAdditionalWorkNow();
});
sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, sqlCommand);
```

**However**

I think that you are overcomplicating your programming life. The queries that you are executing are not long running and you would be perfectly fine executing them with the synchronous version:

```
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i know it. but how? please see Update in question.

Comment: do you see my update? i use your method but my second query (when call DonwloadCompleted()) didn't run. I think about synchro method but i'm not sure. if 1000 users call query at one time???

Comment: @TheX: Can you show the exact code that isn't working? I suspect that there is a disconnect between what you have and what I think you have. Also, your code should work just fine if 1000 users call it simultaneously. However, I would strongly recommend that you change your dynamic SQL to a stored procedure, which will greatly reduce the total amount of work that has to be done each time a query is executed.

Comment: please see updates... I post all My code. I don't know Stored Procedure yet but i try when code start works fine) Now code works only with my first method (with Sleep() call).

Comment: @TheX: All of your code looks correct, but I can easily see various conditions where updating the database asynchronously will cause problems because you don't have a guaranteed order of execution. For example, you could get the progresschanged and completed events very close together and it could be possible for the download sql update to finish executing asynchronously faster than the progress, which means that the download sql would execute, then the progress sql. I think that you would be much better off switching to synchronous database updates.

Comment: Hm... I think so.. but.. I must be sure that synchronous queries didn't slow down performance.

Comment: @TheX: I honestly don't think that they will. We have clients that execute thousands of transactions per minute and there is no issue. There are three critical pieces to keep in mind: 1) As much of your SQL as possible should be in stored procs; 2) Bump up the number of open connections in your connection pool if needed (default is 100, changeable on the connection string) 3) Avoid excessive opening and closing of connections if possible.

Answer (score 4):

you could use `AsyncCallback` instead of `Sleep()`

```
AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback);
sqlcommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, sqlcommand);
```

handles the Async state using callback.

```
private void HandleCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
  SqlCommand command = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;
  command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
  ....
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

the codes overall are good however , are you allowed multiples files download in one unique id ? if you are downloading different files with same unique Id It could update the downloads table which reporting incomplete progress.

Not sure what you mean `DownloadCompleted` only work in debug mode however you could use a private variable in your WebMethod to control flow. Speaking with that, since you are using DB to reporting status changed but not inserting large amount of data you should consider using sync queries so that it could better archive the result.

Comment: I also tried this method, but sql query runs only one time. PS. My method with Sleep() will be slow down performance of WebService and server?

Comment: what do you mean by sql query runs only one time.
Yes, dealing with large amount of data, you don't want to wait(using sleep() in your case) until entire result is processed and handling it require large amount of RAM.
This is just a better designed to utilize asynchronous pattern to data process as soon as it become available in Callback function.

Comment: i mean that when i view my DB in Server Managament, there is only first run of sql query. it's doesn't updated anymore.

Comment: please see Update i question. Thanks.

Comment: could you post the webclient code snippet to show how you setup your DownloadCompleted event? 
Seem like the problem you have is related to the webclient function rather than BeginExecuteNonQuery